# I want make Dynamic window content(img&font&frame) size in WPF at c#

Tags: c#, wpf, resize, window, size

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9T9F.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RE8cL.jpg)

I want to fill the monitor's full screen with 1024*768 ratio of window size& content size.

When use at wide monitor's Fill Blank Right Left Area fill black color whit use x:Name="wide_Out"
how can I make dynamic Full screan window & contents (keep main win size rate), regardless of monitor resolution and type.

**mainwindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="C.MainWindow"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:M_C"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1024" WindowStyle="None">
     <Grid x:Name="wide_Out" Margin="0,0,0,0">
         <Grid Height="768" Width="1024">
             <DockPanel x:Name="L_black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="737" 
             LastChildFill="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="62" 
             Background="#FF242424">
                 <Button Margin="15,8,0,0" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  Width="30"/>
             </DockPanel>
             <DockPanel x:Name="T_blue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" 
              LastChildFill="False" Margin="62,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              Width="954" Background="#FF248BC7">
                 <TextBlock Margin="200,10,200,0" Height="80" 
                 TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="554"/>
            </DockPanel>
            <DockPanel x:Name="L_blue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="637" 
            LastChildFill="False" Margin="62,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="82" Background="#FF248BC7"/>
            <DockPanel x:Name="R_blue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="637" 
            LastChildFill="False" Margin="934,100,0,0" Background="#FF248BC7" 
            Width="82"/>
            <DockPanel x:Name="B_blue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" 
            LastChildFill="False" Margin="144,637,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="790" Background="#FF248BC7">
                <Image Margin="250,15,250,15" Height="70" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="290" />
            </DockPanel>
            <DockPanel x:Name="main_content_panel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Height="537" LastChildFill="False" Margin="144,100,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="790">
                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
                </Grid>
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
     </Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you need to do is wrap the content of your  `Window` element with a `Viewbox`. Here is sample code, from every element I have I have only written the parts that are important, other may be set as needed:

```
<Window
    Height="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}" 
    Width="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}" <!--To set your window size to the size of monitor-->
    WindowStyle="None" <!--To not display any controls-->
    >
    <Viewbox> <!--You can try using different 'Stretch' attribute values-->
        <Grid Width="768" Height="1024" x:Name="wide_Out"> <!--Or whatever dimensions you want your 'base' window to work with-->
            <DockPanel x:Name="L_black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="737" LastChildFill="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="62" Background="#FF242424">
                 <Button Margin="15,8,0,0" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30"/>
             </DockPanel>
             <DockPanel x:Name="T_blue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" LastChildFill="False" Margin="62,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="954" Background="#FF248BC7">
                 <TextBlock Margin="200,10,200,0" Height="80" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="554"/>
            </DockPanel>
            <DockPanel x:Name="L_blue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="637" LastChildFill="False" Margin="62,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="82" Background="#FF248BC7"/>
            <DockPanel x:Name="R_blue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="637" LastChildFill="False" Margin="934,100,0,0" Background="#FF248BC7" Width="82"/>
            <DockPanel x:Name="B_blue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" LastChildFill="False" Margin="144,637,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="790" Background="#FF248BC7">
                <Image Margin="250,15,250,15" Height="70" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="290" />
            </DockPanel>
            <DockPanel x:Name="main_content_panel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="537" LastChildFill="False" Margin="144,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="790">
                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
                </Grid>
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</Window>
```

The important parts are the window width and height, the viewbox element and then the actual width and height of the `wide_Out` Grid, with which you will work when setting inner dimensions and margins.

If you want to, you can use `BackgroundColor`attribute of the window to set background color for the area that is not covered by your content when screen's aspect ratio is other than 4:3 (or whatever you set in `wide_Out Grid).

Comment: Thanks to your answer.
It's exactly what I want.